# Excel Macro 1004 error on vlookup function from 2010 to 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I'm new here but excited to find the community.  I'm new to macros, so forgive me if this seems rudimentary but I haven't been able to find an answer in any of the forums yet.

I recorded a macro in Excel 2010 using the following vlookup function:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([@[Campaign Id]],'BAM Raw Data'!C[-5]:C[-4],2,0)"

I'm new to the code side, so I don't quite understand how or why this works as the original vlookup was =VLOOKUP([@[Campaign Id]],'BAM Raw Data'!F:G,2,0), but regardless in 2010 the macro works beautifully.

I sent this macro to my team who are all running Excel 2007 and so far it seems that I continue to get a runtime error 1004 when I run it.  When I go to debug the error, it points me to this vlookup function.

Is there a particular way to code a vlookup in VBA in 2007 vs. 2010 that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you saying that your macro works fine on your machine (which has Office 2010) but fails on other machines (with 2007)?

Comment: That is correct!  It works fine on my machine with 2010, but does not work on machines using 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2007 structured reference syntax is different from Excel 2010 structured reference syntax. The @ sign is not interpreted in 2007.

Change the formula to use normal references, which will work in both versions of Excel.